# LJMU Harvard referencing style

Tags: biblatex

Is there a `biblatex` style that corresponds to Liverpool John Moores University Harvard referencing style?

The style looks like this:

> Nordhaus (1991) has argued that balancing economic growth against abatement of greenhouse gas emissions must be viewed as a cost-benefit analysis.
>
> The Green New Deal, proposed by The Green New Deal Group talks about a “just transition” which will rebalance the economy away from its focus on the south-east and financial services (Elliot et al., 2019).
>
> But Hulme has pointed out that there is a moral question to consider here: in his words, “why are future generations more morally demanding of us than the dispossessed victims of today?” (Hulme, 2019, p.2).
>
> There is a significant body of opinion that contends this is impossible, dating back to Donella Meadows’ 1972 work, The Limits to Growth (Meadows, 1972).
>
> **References**
>
> Elliot, L., Hines, C., Leggett, J., Lucas, C., Murphy, R., Pettifor, A., Secrett, C., Simms, A. and Tily, G. (2019) *The green new deal: a bill to make it happen* [online]. The Green New Deal Group.
>   Available at: https://greennewdealgroup.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/GND_A_Bill_To_Make_It_Happen.pdf
>   [Accessed: 6th January 2020]
>
> Hulme, M. (2019) Is it too late (to stop dangerous climate change)? An editorial. *Wiley Interdisciplinary Reviews: Climate Change* [online], 11(e619).
>   DOI: 10.1002/wcc.619
>   [Accessed: 13th January 2020]
>
> Meadows, D. H., Meadows, D. L., Randers, J. and Behrens, W. W. (1972) *The limits to growth* [online]. New York: Potomac Associates.
>   Available at: https://collections.dartmouth.edu/teitexts/meadows/diplomatic/meadows_ltg-diplomatic.html
>   [Accessed: 12 January 2020]
>
> Nordhaus, W. D. (1991) To slow or not to slow: the economics of the greenhouse effect. *The Economic Journal* [online], 101(407), pp.920–937.
>   Available at: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2233864
>   [Accessed 13th January 2020]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Google search for the style does not result in any hits for a `biblatex` style, so unless there is something on the University intranet I'd say there is no publicly available `biblatex` style.

For the most part the style is an `authoryear` variation, so you could start from `style=authoryear,` and modify it until it meets your needs.

Some prominent features of the style (the [online] brackets, no spaces after "pp.", very similar setup for `url`+`urldate`) are also present in [`biblatex-bath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-bath)'s `style=bath,` so it is worth a try starting from there as well.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=bath, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat{datelabel}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  urlfrom = {available at},
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nussbaum}
dolor \autocite{worman}
sit \textcite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Example bibliography]

There are two inconsistencies in the examples shown in the question [(1) Is there a comma between author and year in parenthetical citations (Elliot et al, 2019) vs (Meadows 1972)? (2) is there a comma before the year in the bibliography ...and Tily, G. (2019) vs Hulme, M., (2019)] and these examples are not quite enough to build a full style, but this could be a start.

In general the standard styles are more suited for modifications than highly customised contributed styles like `biblatex-apa` and `biblatex-chicago`, because customised styles may have to work hard to satisfy all requirements. But `biblatex-bath` appears to be a well written style that is a solid base for mild modifications.

Comment: Thanks for spotting those inconsistencies and for the reply. To answer your questions: [1] There is a comma between author and year in parenthetical citations. [2] No comma in the bibliography. I've corrected the example I gave.

Comment: @KevinMiddleton Updated the code for question 2, but not the image.